# Jasig - CAS - Windows session

Tags: windows, session, cas, jasig

Is it possible to integrate CAS with the authentification and SSO from multiple applications ( let's say 2 in php and 1 in java) straight from the Windows' session, so the user don't have to auth from an other login form?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved via CAS's SPNEGO module. You'll need a browser that supports Integrated Windows Authentication alone with the user and  the computer have to be members of an Active Directory domain. Implementation details can be found at: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/SPNEGO.